# Is there a way to not repeat the stock Tickers?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, repeat

```
import json
from io import StringIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import pandas as pd


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

url = "https://thestockmarketwatch.com/markets/after-hours/trading.aspx"
driver.minimize_window()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
Afterhours = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'symbol'})

for a in Afterhours:
    print(a.text)
    print("")


driver.quit()
```

Hey guys, I am coding this After-Hours Gapper **scraper** and I have some trouble. The Stock Tickers are repeating it selves. How can i only get the , on the website displayed ones, and the repeated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because if you look at the Inspect element tab and search for the class name `symbol` you get more than 30 results meaning there are more classes with that name than you want.

Let me show you, look at these two images:

[image]

[image]

The first image has the data that you want but the second image also has the same data inside the same class. So you have to find a way to differentiate these two. There are probably many ways to do it but I'm sharing you the one way I found helpful.

```
import json
from io import StringIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager    # new import
import requests
import pandas as pd

# better way to initialize the browser and driver than specifying path everytime
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# option.add_argument('--headless') # uncomment to run browser in background when not debugging
option.add_argument("--log-level=3")
option.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
CDM = ChromeDriverManager(log_level='0')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CDM.install(), options=option)


# PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

url = "https://thestockmarketwatch.com/markets/after-hours/trading.aspx"
driver.minimize_window()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
Afterhours = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'symbol'})
removed_duplicates =[]         

for a in Afterhours:
    if a.find_previous().get('style') == None:      # the difference between those two duplicates
        removed_duplicates.append(a)

for i in removed_duplicates:
    print(i.text)
    print()     # just an empty print() would print a new line
driver.quit()
```

You would've probably noticed by now that the first tag **did not** have any **inline styles** but the second tag had some. The best thing about using `BeautifulSoup` is that it helps in traversal smoothly so you can move up and down the elements finding whatever you need.

I have also added a few improvements and advices in your code, if you are already aware of them kindly ignore. It was a good question!

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the answer i figured it myself but you tweaked the program a lot thank you so much:)